# How to create Poll or MCQ question in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, cocoapods

How can I create poll like this in swift, been looking for a while to find a way to create this but in vain. Do anyone have idea please help me

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: you can subclass UIProgressView maybe?

Comment: good idea .. Thanks Buddy :)